# How to implement function with optional animation in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, swift3

I want to implement a function in Swift 3 which change something in UI. I want to add to this function a parameter to decide if this changes will do with/without animation.

My function:

```
func doSomeChanges(animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            //UI changes
        }
    }
    else {
        //UI changes
    }
}
```

My 1st is to use inside functions feature from Swift:

```
func doSomeChanges(animated: Bool) {
    func uiChanges() {
        //UI changes
    }

    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            uiChanges()
        }
    }
    else {
        uiChanges()
    }
}
```

2nd is to set duration to 0.0 but I don't know it is a good practice:

```
func doSomeChanges(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animated ? 0.25 : 0.0) {
        //UI changes
    }
}
```

How should this be done correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the function by just creating a block of code like this:

```
func doSomeChanges(animated: Bool) {
    let block = {
        // UI Changes
    }

    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            block()
        }
    } else {
        block()
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution is very similar to inside function

Comment: It is indeed very similar I was just showing the way I would do it and thus indicating which of your methods I would use.  I tend to like the block version because it makes it easy to pass it into the function if the requirements change.